# How to update status to wrong numeric if at least on character exist?

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, sql-function

I work on SQL server 2012 I have issue I can't update status to Numbers only when whole field have digits only from 0 to 9 .
but if it have only one character or precision then it will be not valid .

1222 valid

223g not valid

```
create table #acceptnumbersOnly
(
KeyValue nvarchar(50),
Status nvarchar(50)
)
insert into #acceptnumbersOnly(KeyValue)
values 
('233'),
('g25k'),
('25k'),
('gkg'),
('145'),
('45.5')
```

Expected result will be :

```
KeyValue    Status
233         Numbers only 
g25k        Not Valid Numbers Only
25k         Not Valid Numbers Only
gkg         Not Valid Numbers Only
145         Numbers only 
45.5        Not Valid Numbers Only
```

Comment: In all of your research and attempts did you stumble across anything close to `like '%[^0-9]%'`? Perhaps with `!= ''`? And `is not NULL`? Or is it that you can't find `update`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
update #acceptnumbersOnly
set
  [Status]=iif(KeyValue LIKE '%[^0-9]%', 'Not Valid Numbers Only', 'Numbers only');
```

Results

```
KeyValue    Status
233         Numbers only
g25k        Not Valid Numbers Only
25k         Not Valid Numbers Only
gkg         Not Valid Numbers Only
145         Numbers only
45.5        Not Valid Numbers Only
```

Comment: How does your answer handle "but if it have only one character or precision then it will be not valid"? What does it mean?

Comment: The statement says "if there is any character other than 0, 1, 2, ..., 9 in the KeyValue column, then the Status is set to 'Not Valid Numbers Only'.  The string '45.5' is evaluated as TRUE because it contains a dot '.'

Comment: Doesn't the Requirements Document section "but if it have only one character or precision then it will be not valid" mean that `'½'` and `'7'` "will be not valid" because "if it have only one character"? Your statement will treat `'7'` as valid. I still don't know what the invalid "precision" looks like, or whether it is qualified by "one". (It takes extra work to help a [Help Vampire](https://web.archive.org/web/20180216144029/https://www.skidmore.edu/~pdwyer/e/eoc/help_vampire.htm).)

Comment: It produces the outcome requested, no?  Perhaps the Requirements Document section means "'½' and '7'" (together, i.e. '7½') would not be valid.  If so then the code demonstrates the requirement I think

Answer (score 1):

I grew up with the Case...When logic.  This works for me.

```
SELECT KeyValue, 
CASE
    WHEN KeyValue LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN 'Not Valid Numbers Only'
    ELSE 'Numbers only'
END AS Status
FROM #acceptnumbersOnly
```

[image]

I always thought IIF was for MS Access.  I just found out about the IIF function right now.  Apparently IIF was introduced in SQL Server 2012+.  I would think the Case...When is a better solution, as it is portable across all versions of SQL Server.  MAybe it's a moot point, because there probably are not too many people out there using pre-2012 SQL Server.

Comment: It's +1 from me for offering the choice.  Yes, IIF is stigmatized by its earlier availability in Access.  For me it's a little more formal because it requires the ELSE condition be provided.  In a numeric non nullable column if someone leaves off the ELSE 0 in case logic it could cause an issue at some point.  It's functionally equivalent so whatever people are most comfortable with that's best for them.